# Синий экран 0x000000C5

Tags: bsod, windows, windows-7, экран

Подскажите, синий экран `0x000000C5` при старте системы (win 7) безопасный (любой), режим восстановления ловят тот же синий экран. `liveCD` ни одна не грузится либо такая же ошибка либо просто виснут. Пытался поставить винду, получил этот же синий экран. `linux` стартует отлично. Что делать?

Comment: я б попробовал memtest.

Comment: за один круг ошибок не появилось, гонять долго не было времени.да и врятли бы linux завелся не ругнувшись не разу. из-за перегрева такое возможно?

Comment: думаю что в перегреве дело, может  win, драйвер свой кривой ставит какой нибудь?!

Comment: ОЧЕНЬ врядли про драйвер. потому что я ловля синий экран сразу после windows starting, при этом не важно устанавливаю я винду или стартую уже установленную. да и xp не ставит обычно дрова на сетевуху. но при старте эффект тот же.

Answer (score 2):

Как советовало руководство по винде (кажется 98 года): "отключите все новые устройства и повторите загрузку", на самом деле я отключил бы всё, что отключается.. после мемтеста, конечно

```
The 0x000000C5 stop error (bsod) indicates a problem with the device drivers.
```

что говорит сами знаете о чём.

Comment: пытался стартовать с одной клавой(т.к. без нее грузится в режим восстановления, хотя и в нем тоже синий экран) в корпусе снять ничего нельзя(видяха интегрированная, сетевуха, аудио тоже, озу 1 планка, хард(рабочий) 1 шт,dvd привод 1шт)